# Using CECIL to inject if before Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, .net, mono, .net-assembly, mono.cecil

I'm trying to inject a "if( staticDebugOn ) Console.WriteLine" before each call to Console.WriteLine in a set of assemblies. So far i managed to create the "if( staticDebugOn" however what I dont understand how to find the proper line to inset the instructions.

Do i need to create and analyze a the stack of the CIL Instructions of the method that im changing and then inject the instructions when the stack has the same number of elememts as when after the Console.Write has beeen called ?

```
// Creating field... 
TypeReference bool_type = module.Import( typeof(bool) );
fiDef = new FieldDefinition("staticDebugOn",FieldAttributes.Static|FieldAttributes.Public, bool_type);
type.Fields.Add (fiDef); 

// creating instructions....
var i1 = Instruction.Create( OpCodes.Ldsfld, fiDef );
var i2 = Instruction.Create( OpCodes.Brfalse, i1 );
```

I guess that if Console.WriteLine is called with just a string like : Console.WriteLine( "helloworld" ); its easy to find the right location with the instructions to inject i1 and i2 . that must be before the instruction to insert the strig "helloworld" on the stack, right ?

However, a lot of cases involves a more advanced set of instructions. Consider this piece of code:

```
Console.WriteLine( "My Int was" + myint );
```

Or

```
Console.WriteLine( GetCheckSumAsStr(somefloat+3.0f)+String.Format("{0}",(""+(myint++)) );
```

That will naturally resort in alot of instructions and values being pushed and poppen on top of the stack before actually calling Console.WriteLine.

So to sum up the question, anyone got a clue to how i can figure out where to insert the instruction for any case involving Console.WriteLine( whatever.... )

Cheers!

Comment: #if DEBUG not help you?

Comment: I'm not using the .NET compiler to compile it I have some already compiled assemblies that I need to rewrite using mono CECIL.

Comment: This is exactly why there is Debug and Trace Writeline...

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution to my own question, I essentially emulated a stack and pushed and popped instructions on-top of that stack counting back from the instruction where i needed to insert a "if" before, it's a tricky and complicated issue to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought but maybe it will work? (not that experienced with Cecil)

How about adding a new method, e.g. WriteLine2() that wraps WriteLine, and you replace all calls to WriteLine to WriteLine2? Then within WriteLine2, you can do the checks that you need?